# Why doesn't async eachOf returns value in callback but resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async.js

I iterate thorugh an `js` array with `eachOf` from the [asnyc framework](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachOf) and have a asynchronous function in each iteration. If the `callback` is called and no error was thrown, the code reached the return statement. I'm wondering why the return is ignored and doesn't leave the promise daisy-chain immediately. If I wrap another promise around the `eachOf` function and resolve the value in the callback function, the first level promise is done as expected.

Why is that? Shouldn't the return in the callback function be enough to end the function?

**app1.js**

```js
const module1 = require('./module1');
const errorHandler = require('./error'); //implements custom error handler, e.g. log, mail, prowl, etc.

module1.getSomeVals()
.then(result => {
    console.log('this is result:', result); //this returns undefined because the return in module1 not working
})
.catch(e => {
    errorHandler.handle(e);
});
```

**module1.js**

```js
const async = require('async'); //node module
const db = require('./db'); //custom db class

const module1 = {};

module1.getSomeVals= () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        //some asyncronous function resolves values for next chain element, e.g. database stream
        const resultFromSomeAsyncFunction = [
            {
                foo: 'foo1',
                bar: 'bar1'
            },
            {
                foo: 'foo2',
                bar: 'bar2'
            },
            {
                foo: 'foo3',
                bar: 'bar3'
            },
        ];

        resolve(resultFromSomeAsyncFunction);
    })
    .then(results => {

        let newResults = [];

        async.eachOf(results, (result, index, callback) => {

            return db.query("select * from names where foo = '" + result.foo + "' and bar = '" + result.foo)
            .then(rows => {

                newResults.push(rows);
                console.log('this is rows:', rows);
                callback(null); //doesn't need second parameter, because newResults defined above
            })
            .catch(e => {
                callback(e); //throw e works as well
            });
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            else {
              console.log('this is newResults:', newResults); //this is the new result as expected.
              return newResults; //this return doesn't exit the function as expected and the next log will be reached
            }
        });

        console.log('this is newResults and shouldn\'t reached at all:', newResults); //this line will be reached, but should'nt
    });
};

module.exports = module1;
```

**app2.js**

```js
const module2 = require('./module2');
const errorHandler = require('./error'); //implements custom error handler, e.g. log, mail, prowl, etc.

module2.getSomeVals()
.then(result => {
    console.log('this is result:', result); //this returns the expected newResults array because the wrapped promise resolves the newResults
})
.catch(e => {
    errorHandler.handle(e);
});
```

**module2.js**

```js
const async = require('async'); //node module
const db = require('./db'); //custom db class

const module2 = {};

module2.getSomeVals = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        //some asyncronous function resolves values for next chain element, e.g. database stream
        const resultFromSomeAsyncFunction = [
            {
                foo: 'foo1',
                bar: 'bar1'
            },
            {
                foo: 'foo2',
                bar: 'bar2'
            },
            {
                foo: 'foo3',
                bar: 'bar3'
            },
        ];

        resolve(resultFromSomeAsyncFunction);
    })
    .then(results => {

        let newResults = [];

        return new Promise(resolve => { 
            async.eachOf(results, (result, index, callback) => {

                return db.query("select * from names where foo = '" + result.foo + "' and bar = '" + result.foo)
                .then(rows => {

                    newResults.push(rows);
                    console.log('this is rows:', rows);
                    callback(null); //doesn't need second parameter, because newResults defined above
                })
               .catch(e => {
                    callback(e); //throw e works as well
                });
            },
            (err) => {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                else {
                  console.log('this is newResults:', newResults); //this is the new result as expected.
                  resolve(newResults); //this resolve exit the function as expected and the next log wont be reached
                }
            });
        });

        console.log('this is newResults and shouldn\'t reached at all:', newResults); //this line wont be reached as expected
    });
};

module.exports = module2;
```

Module2 has a code style like a mess. I want to have a clean and stable structure in code.

> The docs of [async eachOf](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachOf) says:
>   A callback which is called when all iteratee functions have finished, or an error occurs. Invoked with (err).
>   **Returns:** a promise, if a callback is omitted
>   **Type** Promise

Considering that no callback like `resolve` is available anymore, I except that a return should end up the promise. I want to understand, why is the behavoir like this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also if I had a custom catch handler in `module2.getSomeVals()` app.js?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant custom errorHandler, not catchHandler. I didn't want to cause confusion. I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: The updated code converts rejection into fulfillment with the value `undefined`. That's usually a bad idea. If you're returning the promise chain (as you are in that case), don't handle rejections; let the caller who's receiving the chain handle errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much, but I don't want to waste your time. It's clear what you said - I got it. If i reject an error, without a catch in that chain, it will be undefined. Is `throw` is the way it does, isn't it?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying you're handling the error at the wrong level, and doing that the way you are above in `app2.js` means that whatever `return module2.getSomeVals()...` is returning to will never see a rejection. Instead, it will only see fulfillment, but sometimes that fulfillment value will be `undefined`. Instead, remove `catch` and put it at the top of the call chain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to understand what you mean. You wrote two comments above *let the caller who's receiving the chain handle errors*. The caller is in `app2.js` and it has a `catch()` with errorHandler. After that you wrote *Instead, remove catch and put it at the top of the call chain.*. Thats the part I don't understand. What do you recommend, where exactly should it go?

Comment: It's hard to be specific because `app2.js` has a syntax error. You have a `return` that isn't inside any function. Is that code in a function? Or does it not have the `return`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is only the structure in production. And you are right, in app is no return. It is a mistake in my question.

Comment: Okay. Then it's fine. Basically, one of the rules of promises is: You must either handle errors or return the promise chain to something that will. Your code is (now) handling errors without returning the chain, so it's fine. If it were returning the chain, you wouldn't want the `catch` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `async` version [3.0.x](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) `async.eachOf` returns a `promise` if a callback is omitted.

> #### Returns:
>
> a promise, if a callback is omitted

If it's needed to call that function in a `daisy-chain` it could be used like this:

```js
const async = require('async');

(function f() {
    let items = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        items.push({
            name: 'name' + i,
            age: 20 + i
        });
    }

    let newItems = [];

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true);
        }, 500);
    })
      .then(res1 => {

          console.log('this is res1:', res1);

          return async.eachOf(items, (item, index, callback) => {

              console.log('this is item:', item);

              setTimeout(() => {
                  newItems.push({
                      name: item.name + ' Fixl',
                      age: item.age + index + 1
                  });

                  callback();

              }, 500);

          }); //<-- here is no callback function anymore. if it's that async will make a promise of this function - since v. 3.0.x
      })
      .then(res2 => {
          console.log('this is res2:', res2); //this is undefined, because async returns nothing
          console.log('this is newItems:', newItems); // this is the array with async handled values

          return newItems;
      })
      .catch(e => {
          console.error('error:', e);
      });
})();
```

Since this answers the original question, this answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
        (err) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            else {
              console.log('this is newResults:', newResults); //this is the new result as expected.
              return newResults; //this return doesn't exit the function as expected and the next log will be reached
            }
        });
```

Actually, this return statement *does* exit the function. The thing is, it's on the last line of the function anyway (what's left are some closing `}`s). The next `log` is a part of different executive context. The code structure is roughly

```
async.eachOf(results,
    successHandlingCallback,
    errorHandlingCallback /* <- your callback is inside here */ );

console.log('this is newResults and shouldn\'t reached at all:', newResults); // <- outside, no way of knowing what happened inside the callbacks
```

Callbacks are kind of "fire and forget", if you want to process the results further, you'll be better off following the Promise recipe.

Comment: So, do you mean the setup with `app2.js` and `module2.js` is the way to go?